# How to access controls from MainWindow?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, controls

I have a text box in the MainWindow. I was wondering how I can access it from another window. I tried declaring an instance of the MainWindow but it doesn't work. Say I want to set the text in the MainWindow to something, in SecondWindow. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more code, why declaring instance didn't help you?

Answer (score 2):

Expose a public function on MainWindow that will allow you to set some property on it. Then when creating the new window pass an instance of MainWindow to its constructor. Now from within this new window call the public function you have exposed.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do you do that? I've researched on site but found nothing that i need. I am a novice.

Comment: You make your second form have a constructor which takes an instance of MainWindow and you store it in a provate field: `public FooWindow(MainWindow mainWindow) { _mainWindow = mainWindow; }`. Then from this second window you can always call `_mainWindow.SomeMethod()` where SomeMethod will be a public method on the main window that will do the necessary processing.

Comment: You mean VB.NET? Of course. Anything that works in C# should work in VB.NET as well. After all, both get compiled to the same MSIL.

Comment: I mean, if i do like, 

Public Sub FooWindow(MainWindow mainWindow)

End Sub

it says that mainWindow has a syntax error.

Comment: Oh ok Thanks Darin! I'll try this and get back if I can't get it to work.

Comment: @will0809, VB.NET is not case sensitive so I guess it confuses the name of the variable mainWindow with the actual type. Try using a different name.